# Notation for Hadamard product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation

For multiplying matrices $A_1, ..., A_n$ together I can use the notation $\prod_{i=1}^n A_i$. What is the corresponding notation if these are element-wise multiplications?

Answer (score 0):

That would be the [Hadamard Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)).

Defined by, for any two $m \times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$:
$$(A \circ B)_{ij} = A_{ij} B_{ij}$$